# How to redirect a handle to a different file

Tags: windows, handle

I have a process that has a handle to a file on my PC. I know the handle details (ID? it's a number: 0x6a8), and the file it currently relates to, and I'd like to redirect the handle to a different file. I have no idea if this is possible, how hard it will be, or what the best way to go about achieving my goal is, I'm happy to program in vb.net or python - but I feel like a program like ProcessHacker or ProcessExplorer might be a better shout; I don't know if either of these can do what I want, I've had a play with them but I'm a little out of my depth.

Comment: Windows doesn't support redirecting a handle to reference another object, i.e. there's no equivalent to Unix `dup2` for handles.

Comment: @eryksun so there's no way to do this?

Comment: I know it's not supported. I don't know whether someone has written a driver hack that can modify the handle table of a process.